# JWPlayer: 'Video not found' but paths are correct

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-plugins, jwplayer

I am trying to get a video working with JWPlayer. But I get the error:

`Video not found or access denied`

I have several other videos working with it on the site already but this ones presents and iseeu.

Ive made sure the .js and .swf files are in their correct places.

The path to the video is correct - Ive checked and recheck and tried making it an absolute path (http://www.mysite.com/videos/myvid.mp4 instead of just videos/myvid.mp4).

The permissions to the file and folders are correct.

The only thing I can think of is that prior to uploading I changed the extension from .mpg to .mp4

Video runs fine on my machine but maybe this JWPlayer doesnt like it?

Any suggestions are welcome!

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>  
<div id='mediaplayer'></div>  
<script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player.swf', 'id': 'playerID', 'width': '640','height': '360', 'file': 'http://mysite.com.au/assets/files/lbm.mp4' }); </script>
```

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan added above

Comment: well, that seems odd. You can try this to check [link](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you changing from mpg to mp4? I mean was it named mpg by mistake or is it a mpg file? If it is actually a mpg file it cannot be played by jwplayer. You have to convert it to a mp4 file. Use something like ffmpeg. Renaming is not the solution.

If it was simply named .mpg but was actually a mp4 file then there should be no issues. Why don't you either check the format of the file on vlc or ffprobe and check.

See http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats for supported format details

Comment: Ah yes thanks! Someone told me that because .mpg and .mp4 where essentially very similar just changing the extension would convert them, however that doesnt seem to be the case. I got someone to convert the file properly in video editing software and it seems ok now.

Answer (score -2):

Try using absolute URL. I read another form where this worked.

Comment: Where was the link you found? Cite sources!